# Why in fstream the write method definition asks for a const char*? C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I don´t understand why the definition of this function asks for a const char* and why does it have to be type char?

`file.write(const char* buffer, sizeof buffer);`

Comment: Char is the byte type

Comment: `const` because the buffer passed will not be modified.   `char *` because a `char` is the smallest possible unit of storage in standard C++ - every possible object that may be written will consist of one or more `chars`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `file` stream is declared to use the `char` type for its underlying data (ie, `std::fstream` is an alias for `std::basic_fstream<char>`), so that is why  `write()` wants a `char*` pointer. And the pointer is to `const` data because `write()` does not modify the data.